How does Conan handle dev libraries?
I'm using Conan to install ffmpeg. The installation fails due to a missing dependency libva-dev - there is no Conan recipe for it and it is not installed on the system.
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libva-dev
[...]
ConanException: System requirements: 'libva-dev' are missing

libva has a Conan recipe. I notice that Conan does not seem to have recipes for *-dev libraries. This makes sense because dev libraries are basically special cases of normal libraries that additionally include header files, which Conan probably already has to deal with as part of the design.
When Conan requires dev libraries, what is the Conan way to handle that?
Can I point libva-dev to libva and have it work? Does it mandate a separate libva-dev Conan recipe?

conan profile detect --force
conan install conanfile.txt --build=missing

conanfile.txt
[requires]
ffmpeg/6.1


I do not have root access.

It would probably be better to submit a ticket to: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues, and specify the Linux distro. The recipes that contain "system_requirements" have some mappings to different distros. It is possible that the recipe for ffmpeg needs a fix, or maybe it is just a matter of configuring the Conan conf for the "system_requirements" of your distro.

Is that to say Conan recipes should never use dev libraries? I wanted to ask the Conan community before opening an issue, as I am new, and am not sure whether this is a common or solved problem. Also, this happens on 2 different distros - Ubuntu 22.04 and WSL Debian 12.

The ffmpeg is a complex package and requires more system packages. It uses the package vaapi/system and maybe it can be replaced. However, it still requires vdpau-dev and xorg that are installed from the system. In case you can not use root to install, you still can use a Docker container to isolate and have privileges. Still, it would be better opening an issue to Conan directly. Me and drodri are part of Conan Community too.

You misunderstand, I am building on Electron, it must build on the OS, it cannot be containerized. Also, if you must know I already solved this today using conda. I already knew conda was strong enough, probably also a better solution for Python at the moment (popularity/integration), I just don't like conda. The Conan aspect of this question still stands. Since conda installed libva=2.21.0 and not libva-dev I now think this is a Conan bug. https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/issues/24228
